# Semantic ui sidebar implementation

Tags: css, html, button, semantic-ui

Hello how do i implement the sidebar from semantic ui?  I would like to use the first example on the list.

http://semantic-ui.com/modules/sidebar.html#/definition

I tried copy-pasting the whole div section and putting it on my html
For the javascript(? not really sure), the

```
$('.left.demo.sidebar')
.sidebar('toggle')
;
```

i tried putting it on 
 button onclick , and
 function then using href to call
but sidebar is not showing.. what am i doing wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to include the `jQuery` library in the `<head></head>` section of your page:

```
<script language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And the `semantic.js` file:

```
<script language="javascript" src="[your path here]/semantic.js"></script>
```

Which you have to download from:

http://semantic-ui.com/

(It's located inside the folder dist. Copy that file in the desire location and populate `src` with the right path)

---

BETWEEN `<HEAD></HEAD>`:

```
<script language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="[your path here]/semantic.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.left.demo.sidebar').sidebar('toggle');
    });

</script>
```

Comment: then i put it in an onclick? Thanks! Will try

Comment: i still cant make it trigger.. I copied the exact same codes, my code is 
<a class="ui left floated yellow icon  button" id="toggle" onclick="$('.left.demo.sidebar')
   .sidebar('toggle')
   ;">

Comment: Not need to grab that onclick, that's wrong, just use the code you have in your question, check my answer again, I will upgrade it.

Comment: the .left.demo.sidebar is the ID of the sidebar and toggle is the ID of the button? I kinda made it work using the example here https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/945
but I can't figure out a way YET to close it. Thanks!

Comment: My toggle becomes disabled when the sidebar is called. I can close it if i add another button on my sidebar but I want to allow the toggle to still be clickable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you add jQuery to your project you can trigger your sidebar by adding this code to your .js file:

```
$('.element.to.trigger.sidebar').on('click', function () {
   $('.left.demo.sidebar')
      .sidebar('toggle');
});
```